# Form variable is not being defined?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form where I want to check a box and from that 
record get the emp_id from ONLY the record that are check (name="add#cnt#")

```
<cfform method="post" action="approver.cfm" >   
    <cfoutput>
    <input type="hidden" name="txtTotalRecords" value="#totalEmployees.recordcount)#">
    </cfoutput>
  <table >
 .....                                                                
        <cfoutput query="totalEmployees">          
        <tr >                                            

        <cfset cnt= cnt+1>  
        <td><cfif #approver# eq 1>Yes <cfelse>No </cfif></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name="add#cnt#" value="yes"></td>   
        <td><input type="hidden"  name="emp_id#cnt#" value="#emp_id#"></td>   
        </tr>
          </cfoutput> 
      <cfoutput>
      <input type="hidden" name="f_cnt" value="#cnt#">        
      </cfoutput>

        </table>

         <p><input type="submit"  name="Submit" value="submit" ></p>    
 </cfform>
```

For testing purpose once i submit the form im selecting the record(s), eventually
I will update a table.

But once I submit the form I get error:
Variable form.add1 is undefined.

```
<cfloop from="1" to ="#form.f_cnt#" index="j">
    <cfset emp_id =#evaluate("form.emp_id#j#")#>
    <cfset add =#evaluate("form.add#j#")#>
    <cfdump var=#emp_id#>
</cfloop>
    <cfif emp_id neq "" and add neq "">
       <cfquery name="output" datasource="phonelist">
          select * from employee where emp_id=#emp_id#
       </cfquery>
    </cfif>
<cfdump var=#output#>
```

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

How can I select the records that only have been check?

I made a http://jsfiddle.net/j65wh9hz/  to be able to view all my code.

Comment: Update how? Are you are updating all of the selected emp_id's with the same value? If so, it might be simpler to give the fields the same name, so the selected id's are passed as a comma delimited list ie "1,2,18,242". You can then use that list with a `UPDATE Table SET Col = 'Yes' WHERE IN (...list of ids ...)` clause.

Comment: Stop using `cfform` and its related tags. They are not necessary and will eventually cause you more headaches than they are worth. use plain old HTML `form` and `input`

Comment: @scottsroz the reason i was using cfform was because i was using cfselect

Comment: @leigh Thanks, good tip, but it will be with different values

Comment: Hm.. then why did you select the answer that does just that :) ? Granted with a SELECT versus an UPDATE, but same concept. Sounds like there is some other stuff going on we can't see.

Comment: @leigh you are correct it will have to be different since it will actually be a update not select

Comment: Well you *can* use it with a sql UPDATE. But only if you are updating *all* of the selected records to the same value. Say your form contains a text field called "note#x#", next to each checkbox. The "notes" for each id would different. So you would need to run individual UPDATE's for each record ID. I am not saying that it IS what you are doing. Just trying to explain when you can - and cannot - use the list approach.

Comment: thanks, got this part to work, you are correct to assume there are other stuff (values) that im not showing here ,like a select

Comment: @jfishbow If you wouldn't mind, I'd be really curious to see the rest of your form code, and even your form processing code. You can append it to this Question or drop in in a pastebin and link it in comments. You did alright with you what you came up with and really, you were almost there.

Comment: @CRQUERYPARAM, i just dont want to put all the code here , but thanks for asking, cool username by the way

Comment: what i mean by HERE i mean make it public

Comment: I understood, and I understand. Merely thought I/we could help you handle your form more efficiently so that next time, you need not even ask. Good luck. :)

Comment: @cfquertparam if there was another way i could show you that be nice

Answer (score 9):

If a checkbox is not checked, it is not submitted with the form. Check for its existence by doing:

```
<cfloop from="1" to ="#form.f_cnt#" index="j">
   <cfif structKeyExists(form, "add#j#")>
      <cfset checkbox = form["add#j#"] />
      <!--- do stuff --->
   </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Also, notice how the code above avoids `evaluate()` by using associative array notation. Evaluate() is rarely needed.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, there's a better way to use checkboxes.

Name them all the same thing with differing values (vs naming them all different things with the same value -- 'Yes' -- as you have done.

You also do not need to use the variable `cnt` for simple query output like this, you can use `#currentrow#`, but that's just semantics.

```
<cfform method="post" action="approver.cfm" >   
    <cfoutput>
    <input type="hidden" name="txtTotalRecords" value="#totalEmployees.recordcount)#">
    </cfoutput>
  <table >
 .....                                                                
        <cfoutput query="totalEmployees">         
        <tr >                                           

        <cfset cnt= cnt+1>  
        <td><cfif #approver# eq 1>Yes <cfelse>No </cfif></td>
        <!--- Changed the checkbox's name to AddBox and the value to #emp_id# --->
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name="AddBox" value="#emp_id#"></td>
        <!--- As a tip, field names are easier to visibly read as EmpID_#cnt# or Emp_ID_#cnt# vs Emp_id#cnt# 
            but the this field should not be needed. --->
        <td><input type="hidden"  name="emp_id#cnt#" value="#emp_id#"></td>   
        </tr>
          </cfoutput> 
      <cfoutput>
      <!--- You can remove this hidden field --->
       <input type="hidden" name="f_cnt" value="#cnt#">     
       </cfoutput>

        </table>

         <p><input type="submit"  name="Submit" value="submit" ></p>    
 </cfform>
```

And then, for formprocessing.

```
<!--- changing the cfloop below from <cfloop from="1" to ="#form.f_cnt#" index="j"> --->
<cfloop list="#form.AddBox#" index="j">
    <!--- There's no need to use evaluat("form.#variable#"), you can use form[variable] --->
    <cfset emp_id = form["emp_id#j#"]
    <cfset add =#evaluate("form.add#j#")#>
    <cfdump var=#emp_id#>
</cfloop>
    <!--- Because this was not in the cfloop, it only processes on the last emp_id --->
    <cfif emp_id neq "" and add neq "">
       <cfquery name="output" datasource="phonelist">
          select * from employee where emp_id=#emp_id#
       </cfquery>
    </cfif>
<cfdump var=#output#>
```

So we can to fix it like this

```
<!--- changing the cfloop below from <cfloop from="1" to ="#form.f_cnt#" index="j"> --->
<cfloop list="#form.AddBox#" index="j">
    <!--- There's no need to use evaluate("form.#variable#"), you can use form[variable] --->
    <cfset emp_id = form["emp_id#j#"]
    <cfset add =#evaluate("form.add#j#")#>
    <cfdump var=#emp_id#>

    <cfquery name="output" datasource="phonelist">
        select * from employee where emp_id=#emp_id#
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var=#output#>
```

But finally, there's no reason to loop over it, we can do this

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form,"AddBox") and len(form.addbox)>
    <cfquery name="output" datasource="phonelist">
        select * from employee where emp_id in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_int" value="#form.AddBox#" list="yes">)
    </cfquery>
    <cfdump var=#output#>
</cfif>
```

Final notes

- We have to use StructKeyExists(form,"AddBox") (or isDefined("form.AddBox")) to make sure that the variable exists - in this case, to ensure that at least one checkbox is checked.
- A `<cfparam name="form.AddBox" default="">` cause the cfif StructKeyExists to pass, so that's why then len is also there.
- We can use an sql IN statement to look for any records where the table's emp_id is in the list of values provided from the checkbox AddBox.
- This does make the assumption that emp_id is a primary key.
- CFQUERYPARAM is important. It blocks sql injection attacks from making unintended changes to your table/database. Look it up for other queries.
- Finally, rather than a cfif to display yes or no. If Approver is always equal to 0 or 1, you can yes #YesNoFormat(Approver)#, one of cf's built-in functions

### In conclusion, your final code could look like this.

(this is the code to use)

```
<cfform method="post" action="approver.cfm" >   
    <cfoutput>
    <!-- Final note, I don't think this field is needed --->
    <input type="hidden" name="txtTotalRecords" value="#totalEmployees.recordcount#">
    </cfoutput>
    <table >
 .....                                                                
        <cfoutput query="totalEmployees">         
        <tr>                                            
            <td><cfif #approver# eq 1>Yes <cfelse>No </cfif></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="AddBox" value="#emp_id#"></td>
            <td><!--- removed emp_id hidden field ---> </td>   
        </tr>
         </cfoutput>
    </table>

         <p><input type="submit"  name="Submit" value="submit" ></p>    
 </cfform>
```

### And your processing

Use this as well

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form,"AddBox")>
    <cfquery name="output" datasource="phonelist">
        select * from employee where emp_id in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.AddBox#" list="yes">)
    </cfquery>
    <cfdump var=#output#>
</cfif>
```

Suppose that you do want to include data with each row that contained Approver status, you were on the right track, you would use a syntax like `<input type="hidden" name="Approver_#emp_id#" value="#Approver#">` and then you could reference it something like this:

(This isn't code to use, only an example)

```
<cfoutput><cfloop list="#form.addbox#" index="a">
  The value of this index is #a#.<br>
  The associated approver status is #form["Approver_#a#"]#
</cfloop></cfoutput>
```

Suppose, for example, you wanted to use this data to make lists of the checked people who were approved and who were not approved, and the values were always either 0 or 1 (for Approver).

```
<cfset Approval0 = "">
<cfset Approval1 = "">
<cfloop list="#form.addbox#" index="a">
  <cfset appstatus = form["Approver_#a#"]>
  <cfset variables["Approval#appstatus#"] = ListAppend(variables["Approval#appstatus#"],a)>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>
  The following employee IDs have approval status: #Approval1#<br>
  The following employee IDs do not: #Approval0#
</cfoutput>
```

(Any non-scoped variable, like Approval0 and Approval1, is placed in the scope "variables", which is what allows me to use variables["Approval#appstatus#"] rather than #Evaluate("Approval#appstatus#")#)

Comment: It is not a matter of better or worse, but how you will be using the values. In cases where you are applying the same action to all values, then using the same name is better, because you can feed the list to an `IN` clause - as I mentioned in the comments. But in cases where you need to apply a different action, to each item, then unique field names is usually the better approach, because it usually involves a *set* of related form fields. But again - it depends.

Comment: @Leigh Yes, but there's no reason that checkboxes all should have different names by design. Checkboxes are designed for creating groups. For his simple purpose, this is the proper approach, I'm sure.

Comment: @Leigh Even in a case of subset checkboxes like [ ] User Admin [ ] Content Admin [ ] Mail Admin, you might name the checkboxes all `chkbox#userID#' and give them different values for each admin type. Or this user might use checkboxes like AddBox_#Approver# (where Approver is 0 or 1) and take different for the list in #form.Addbox_0# and #form.Addbox_1#. I know that's a contrived example but I get what you mean.

Comment: They "support" grouping, yes, but I would not say they are designed *only* for grouping. Their primary purpose is to toggle a state on/off. Nothing says you must have a "group" of checkboxes. But that is arguing semantics ;) The point was they can - and are - used in different ways. In a simple scenario, sure, "same name" is simpler. However, with multi-row forms (where you can add/remove rows), dynamic naming via a counter variable is very common. Each "set" of fields is given the same counter suffix to relate the fields `name1,option1`,`name2,option2`.

Comment: Checkboxes are only submitted when checked. So if you give them all the same name, it is more difficult to identify which "set" of fields the selected values are associated with. Whereas with dynamic names ie `name1,option1`,`name2,option2` ...  it is a simple call to `structKeyExists(form, 'option'& counter)`.

Comment: Haha, I got distracted when writing the above and just noticed your comment.

Comment: *RE: you might name the checkboxes all `chkbox#userID#`* Yes, but that assumes an ID is available. For an add/entry form, you would not necessarily have an associated ID yet. You could use that approach for an EDIT form though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63137/discussion-between-leigh-and-cfqueryparam).